# Java code to list in all files from a directory with a particular word in filename

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, filepath, file-processing

I have a directory with huge number of files,I need to list all the files from that directory with a particular word on it's name,like India or else. Also how to get the path of that files?

Comment: You can write your own `FileFilter` - in particular, you'll place your implementation when you @Override `accept()`

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles-java.io.FilenameFilter-

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```
try (Stream<Path> paths = Files.walk(Paths.get("/home/you/Desktop"))) {
    paths
        .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
        // You can also use Apache StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase()
        .filter(path -> path.getFileName().toString().toLowerCase().contains(word.toLowerCase()))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Comment: @JoopEggen woops! Thanks!